# Conveying the idea of "down the road" (i.e. in the future)

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+the+road

> Lots of things will have changed a few years down the road.

**Down the road** is used metaphorically instead of in the future.

One could say

> Beaucoup de choses auront changé dans quelques années.

but I am wondering if there is an informal expression similar to the English one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two good answers already for the example in the question, by [aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39766/13100) and [Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39765/13100). The title, however, appears more open and general than the one example in the question.

For another possible usage of *“down the road”*, where something specific is predicted to happen at some unknown future moment, though its potentiality is already present or imminent, we could envisage ***à un moment donné*** (also ***à moment donné*** in some areas of the francophone world) or ***tôt ou tard*** (not particularly metaphoric, but I tend to agree with Laure’s statement that there are not many colourful equivalents in French, beyond *“l’eau sous les ponts”* already proposed by aCOSwt):

- If we leave it this way, it will come to bite us **down the road**.
  *Si on le laisse ainsi, ça tournera/se virera contre nous **à (un) moment donné**.*
  *Si on ne s’en occupe pas, ça nous retombera sur le nez<sup>1</sup> **tôt ou tard**.*

---

#### Proverbs

Obviously, there’s a proverb for almost anything, so one could perhaps cite one, but it will need to be adapted on a case-by-case basis and likely won’t ever be a general case. But it is one way to transpose an image without falling flat in translation...

For the previous example, it could be some prediction of dark ages:

- ***Qui sème le vent récolte la tempête**. On ne peut pas laisser ça tel quel.*

In another type of use, it could simply be a call to inaction:

- Don’t worry, things will improve down the road regardless.
  *T’inquiète ! **Après la pluie le beau temps** !*

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>From the common image “cracher en l’[air](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/air) pour que cela vous retombe sur le nez”.</sub>

Comment: *tot ou tard* is a really suggestion. *a moment donne* sounds awkward to me and I would rather say *a un moment donne*. Also, *a un moment donne* means *at some point* so it could be used to speak about the past too (see may examples here: https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/%C3%A0+un+moment+donn%C3%A9.html)

Comment: @Taladris Ce qu’en dit [*Le bon usage*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA832&dq=%22%C3%A0+moment+donn%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiv8mL7_PkAhUQJt8KHSVDDh0Q6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20moment%20donn%C3%A9%22&f=false). Usage régional, donc. Merci pour la remarque.

Comment: @Taladris The past would probably use some past tense, not the future like in the example. Also, even when I use it for the past, it still marks a pivotal point in time, something that separates a before and an after. The only difference is that the after has actually happened, while it is still uncertain when or if it will occur when talking about the future.

Comment: D'accord. J'ai aussi appris quelquechose :D

Answer (score 2):

Je ne vois pas d'expression idiomatique imagée pour rendre la même chose.

***Dans*** quelques années convient, même si personnellement je préfère ***d'ici*** quelques années.
 *Dans* amène directement au moment de l'arrivée, alors que ***d'ici*** met l'accent sur l'intervalle dans le temps, tout comme *down* dans l'anglais *down the road*.

Answer (score 2):

Le *down* anglais donne ici l'idée d'*aval* (l'opposé de l'amont) associé au temps qui s'écoule.

Dans l'idée d'écoulement du temps vers le futur, le français préférera sans doute l'image de l'eau qui coule sous les ponts.

*Beaucoup de choses auront changé quand (beaucoup d')/(de l') **eau aura coulé sous les ponts**.*

Le français associe plutôt la *route* (le *chemin*) à la vie. Dans ce champ lexical... l'aval du chemin... c'en est souvent... l'extrémité... terminale...

*Beaucoup de choses auront changé **au bout du chemin**.*

Mais, sans nécessairement aller au bout, on peut aussi avoir :

*Beaucoup de choses auront changé **au long** du chemin*

Comment: *quand de l'eau aura coule sous les ponts* means *in a long time* so it is not always a good choice (the example in the OP is about *in a few years*).

Comment: @Taladris : Perhaps it depends on the bridge ? :-) Anyway... At the end of the day, it's not different from *un bout de temps* which... I'll acknowledge, people feel like eternity particularily when it is *petit*....